# Image drag drop to iframe not working in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, drag-and-drop, drag

I am facing problem in drag drop behavior in chrome browser. I can't drag and drop image on to the iframe from the same location. I can drag and drop from same location but from different tab means If same url is there in two tabs then I can drag drop image from other tab to current tab's iframe.  The mystery is drag and drop of URL into iframe is working even from the same tab. I am stucked, I want the image to be dragged into the iframe from the same tab in google chrome. This functionality is working fine in Firefox without any issue. How to fix this in Chrome.

Comment: Please provide an example. jsbin, jsfiddle, something like that, so we could see it. My first guess is something with relative url of the image, but it's a really wild guess